# Apache mod_rewrite ~userdir to subdomain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I cant find how to redirect

`(optional: www.)domain.pl/~userdir/(optional)page.html` to

`www.userdir.domain.pl/(optional)page.html`

in apache .htaccess.

Examples:

```
domain.pl/~userdir -> www.userdir.domain.pl/
domain.pl/~userdir/page.html -> www.userdir.domain.pl/page.html
www.domain.pl/~userdir -> www.userdir.domain.pl/
www.domain.pl/~userdir/page.html -> www.userdir.domain.pl/page.html
```

Would anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: I doubt you're still looking for advice on this one, but as this page comes up #2 on Google and it has no other advice, consider using mod_vhost_alias instead of userdir+modrewrite http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html